# A Better Way for No Results Returned?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a very simple search page running a query for one table in a DB.  I have the query and fetch working.  But if it doesn't find any matches to the term the user put in then I need it to say "No Rows Returned".

Here is my PHP CODE:

```
<?php

include('./includes/dbConnection.php');

$result = null;


if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {

// connect to database
$conn = dbConnect('localhost', 'db_admin', 'kfor.com', 'receiving');

// query the database
$stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
$searchTerm = "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE pallet = {$_GET['pallet_id']}";
$result = $conn->query($searchTerm);
}
?>
```

Here is the PHP displaying the results and errors:

```
 <?php
        if ($result != null) {
            if (!empty($result)) {
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    ?>

                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row['pallet']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['serial']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php
                }
            }
        } else {
            echo "No Results";
        }
        ?>
```

Is there a better way to display "No Results Returned"?  Right now it's just displaying that error upon refresh because $result does equal null.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: you should use a **prepared statement** or **bind parameter** instead of just straightaway including a value from GET into your query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `$result = null;`, it's not needed. You can check [`num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) returned your query.

```
<?php

include('./includes/dbConnection.php');


if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {

  // connect to database
  $conn = dbConnect('localhost', 'db_admin', 'kfor.com', 'receiving');

  $_GET['pallet_id'] = addslashes($_GET['pallet_id']);
  // query the database
  $stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
  $searchTerm = "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE pallet = {$_GET['pallet_id']}";
  $result = $conn->query($searchTerm);

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          ?>

          <tr>
              <td><?php echo $row['pallet']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['serial']; ?></td>
          </tr>
      <?php
      }
  } else {
      echo "No Results Returned";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: seems, $result is not mysqli result. can you share your dbConnection.php ?

Comment: Still getting an Undefined variable: result error.  :(

Comment: Code:  

http://screencast.com/t/vOyj3Kjt7x45
http://screencast.com/t/LK4O4iIussS

Comment: ah Sorry, try one more time!

Comment: Note: `if ($result->num_rows > 0) {` check should be inside `if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {`
 
Either, your query is not actually executing and, you are checking for num_rows, which is actually undefined.

Comment: are you sure your `$result->num_rows` check is inside `if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {` statement ?

Comment: No, it's not.  I can put it in there but I need my while loop to be within my HTML so I can loop through the results and display them within the HTML portion of the page.

Comment: Your solution technically works but it's echoing the error and my while loop  outside the HTML portion that I need it to be in.

http://screencast.com/t/byKvVAmV7

Comment: You can just, put your html inside `if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {`, also update your question with html, if any problem persist